# Meteor: display different data based on what Session equals

Tags: session, meteor, handlebars.js

Is there a way to use something similar in Meteor to this

```
{{#if $.Session.equals 'sessionName' value1}}
  <p> value1 </p>
{{/if}}
{{#if $.Session.equals 'sessionName' value2}}
  <p> value2 </p>
{{/if}}
{{#if $.Session.equals 'sessionName' value3}}
  <p> value3 </p>
{{/if}}
```

I'm trying to use helpers, but can't get it to work:

```
{{#if 'helperName' value1}}
  <p> value1 </p>
{{/if}}
{{#if 'helperName' value2}}
  <p> value2 </p>
{{/if}}
{{#if 'helperName' value3}}
  <p> value3 </p>
{{/if}}

Template.name.helpers({
  helperName: function (item) {
    return Session.equals('currentItem', item);
  },
});

onBeforeAction: function() {
  Session.set('currentLastItem', 'value1');
  this.next();
}
```

> And I get error statement that there is no such function as helperName

This is the same principle but used to render different data based on the current route - [Meteor: Change the class of link on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25508359/meteor-change-the-class-of-link-on-click/25513954#25513954)

Comment: `{{#if 'helperName' value1}}` the quotes are the wrong way round, you want `{{#if helperName 'value1'}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would allow you to use the syntax you used above:

https://atmospherejs.com/raix/handlebar-helpers